# How to generate CSV file of table with 10 millions of row without affecting production database?

Tags: sql, performance, csv, locking, sqlbulkcopy

How does CSV generation affect SQL performance on SQL Server?

I want to generate CSV files from an active production database. These tables have 10-20-30 million rows stored in them. These are not particularly wide tables, but they are used actively.
Approach would be like: create copies of tables with "SELECT * INTO [newTable] FROM..." - I think it should copy data fast into another table. Export file from copytable, so production table would not get locked unintentionally. I'm not sure if this step is actually necessary, or if it helps anything.

Thanks!

Comment: You must have backup of these production database.  Why not restore the most recent backup in another server and work with that?

Comment: We need the actual state of tables at a given time.